# ¿Cómo modificar el filtro de un Fusion Filter en Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Necesito cambiar el texto predefinido de un filtro "All" por "Todo".

He intentado hacerlo por Javascript, pero no consigo seleccionarlo. La otra opción que he tanteado es ocultarlo por CSS, funciona a medias porque oculto el texto, pero no lo borro, sigue estando pero oculto. El filtro pone una especie de subrayado, que no solo aplica al "Todo" sino al "All", que está oculto.

```
    .fusion-filters .fusion-filter a[data-filter="*"]{
    color:transparent !important;
}
.fusion-filters .fusion-filter a[data-filter="*"]::before {
    content: "Todo";
}
```

Sé que puedo cambiarlo vía Javascript, pero no he sido capaz de dar con la solución. He usado este código.

```
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName('fusion-filter fusion-filter-all');
.innerHTML = "Todo";
</script>
```

Comment: creo que en el selector css deberias reemplazar `a[data-filter="*"]` a esto `a[data-filter]`

Comment: Si elimino el asterisco y pongo tu opción, cambia todos los filtros, no solo el "All".
No funciona

Comment: El selector deberia de quedar algo asi para que funcione `.fusion-filters .fusion-filter a[data-filter]`